# How to dynamically change the view of the centre of BorderPane when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, fxmlloader

I am constructing an application and I am using borderPane as the main layout. I am having a sideBar on the rightPane with different buttons, my goal is to change the centerPane with different views when a corresponding button is clicked from the sideBar (every button sets a new view in the center).

So, my strategy is to make an FXML to each view that corresponds to each button to be loaded in the center when the button is clicked (call it sub scenes) in addition to the FXML of the main layout (BorderPane, call it the main scene) and whenever a button is clicked, the corresponding FXML is loaded in the center of the main scene. The problem is that nodes in the sub scenes do not see or do not have control over nodes in the main scene. For example, a sub scene has a button when it is clicked it should change the text of a button in the sideBar located in the rightPane of the borderPane but that does not work and throws a nullPointerException. Note that all FXMLs has the same controller class.

I am loading sub scenes using this code:

```
private FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("subScene.fxml"));
GridPane subScene = loader.load();
mainWindowLayout.setCenter(subScene);
```

mainWindowLayout
is the BorderPane

Also, is there a better way to do this functionality without loading different FXMLs?

Comment: If all the FXML files use the same controller instance, then they will have access to all of the nodes injected into the controller... Try included a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: How to make all FXML files to use the same controller instance (the same instance created when the main scene is loaded) ?

Comment: have you thougt about building [custom components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components), which could get a reference to mainWindowLayout at construction time point, like new MyCenterComponent(mainWindowLayout)